# For loop reset (reinitializing i to 1 in specific case) - doesn't work as expected?

Tags: c++

I have a predefined function called flip, which changes the order of the elements of a vector like this:

```
for FLIP(9, [3 2 6 8 5 9 1 7 4], 1, 6) ->
v = [9 5 8 6 2 3 1 7 4] 

void FLIP(int x, int v[100], int w, int y)
{
    int aux;
    for (int p = w; p <= y / 2; p++)
    {
        aux = v[p];
        v[p] = v[y - p + 1];
        v[y - p + 1] = aux;
    }
}
```

I must use it like this.

I need to make a program which orders the elements of v ascending. I must use this FLIP function and calls with

```
FLIP(whatever variable I want, whatever array I want, 1, whatever variable I want)
```

basically, the third argument has to be 1 no matter what.

Well, I thought that I might try to get the highest numbers in their place first, by using two FLIP calls. First should be used to get the highest number in v[1], then to move it to v[n].

Then I should reset the for loop, so I can get the other values in their place, with i=1.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work as expected.

This is my program

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void FLIP(int x, int v[100], int w, int y)
{
    int aux;
    for (int p = w; p <= y / 2; p++)
    {
        aux = v[p];
        v[p] = v[y - p + 1];
        v[y - p + 1] = aux;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n, v[100], max = -32000;
    cin >> n;
    int copie = n;
    for (int t = 1; t <= n; t++)
    {
        cin >> v[t];
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (v[i] > max)
        {
            max = v[i];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (max == 1)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (v[i] == max)
        {
            FLIP(n, v, 1, i);
            FLIP(n, v, 1, n);
            i = 1;
            max--;
            n--;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= copie; i++)
    {
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

But for

```
 n = 9
v = [3 2 6 8 5 9 1 7 4]
```

I get
`6 2 3 1 5 4 7 8 9`

I really don't understand why that happens. I didn't think this loop would ever end until max becomes 1, and now I can't understand what is happening.

Can you explain to me what I'm doing wrong and how can I fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: In C++, array indexing starts with 0, so that if the array `arr` contains [2, 3, 5], then arr[0] = 2, arr[1] = 3 and arr[2] = 5. You (and perhaps your teacher) seem to be under the impression that indexing starts with 1. Until you clear this up (at least in your own mind) you have basically no chance of getting this code to work.

Comment: C uses 0-based arrays as well. What Beta said is true for C and C++.

Comment: FIrst of all, I feel bad for you because you're being taught some really horrible C++ which you'll have to unlearn later on. I suggest you read this: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ Here's a hint: After you set `i` to 1 in your main loop, what happens to `i` before the start of the next iteration of the loop?

Comment: I suggest that you try to avoid changing the loop counter inside the loop itself, since that often leads to confusing behavior. Use one loop that loops from `n` to 1, and have a second loop inside the first one that finds the maximum element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the function only once where the maximum value is the first number, so put up an 'if' to check on that.

Start from `i=0` instead of `i=1`, because it will jump straight to the second value every time.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    if (max == 1)
    {
        break;
    }
    if (v[i] == max)
    {
        if (i!=1)
      {
        FLIP(n, v, 1, i);
        FLIP(n, v, 1, n);
      }
        else
        FLIP(n, v, 1, n);

        i = 0;
        max--;
        n--;
    }
}
```